# Making pretty permalinks work in WAMP

Tags: apache, wordpress, mod-rewrite, wamp, permalinks

I am not able to switch to pretty permalinks in WAMP. Changing to any form other than default gives 404 error.
I have switched on the `rewrite_module` in Apache. I Googled the problem and found that following changes should be made to *httpd.conf* file. My *httpd.conf* file stands as

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

I also checked that the *.htaccess* file is getting created. It reads as

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /vit%20web/events/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /vit%20web/events/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you reboot Apache after editing `httpd.conf`?

A bulletproof check for `mod_rewrite` is to remove the `<IfModule>...</IfModule>` tags and try running WordPress - if you get a 500 Server Error, `mod_rewrite` isn't installed.

Also I would recommend changing `<Directory />` to `<Directory "C:/path/to/server/root">` (note the forward slashes too, even on Windows).

And the deny order should be switched if you're only on a development server;

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Answer (score 13):

All you need to do is turn on the mod_rewrite in the wamp settings tab.

`Click Wamp -> Apache -> Apache Modules -> rewrite_module`

If you select that then turn on %postname% it should work

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be:
Whenever you have permalinks in subfolder of your main www folder (i.e.

```
RewriteBase /subdirectory/
```

you may need to have a **.htaccess** file in your main **c:\wamp\www** folder too.